Showing $|x|^{\alpha}$ is an $A_p$ weight for $−d<α<d(p−1)$ (with cubes)
It is know that, the function $x\mapsto |x|^{\alpha},\, x\in\mathbb{R}^d$ belong to the Muckenhoupt class ($-d<\alpha<d(p-1)$). In Showing $|x|^\alpha$ is an $A_p$ weight for $-d<\alpha<d(p-1)$, is proved with balls. Is possible with cubes? I put context:
Definition. A weight is a nonnegative locally integrable function on $\mathbb{R}^d$ that vanishes or takes the value $\infty$ only on a ser of
measure zero.
Definition. Let $1<p<\infty$. The Muckenhoupt class $A_p$ is defined by all weights such that
\begin{align}
A_p(w)=\sup_{Q\text{ cubes in }\mathbb{R}^d}\left(\frac{1}{|Q|}\int_Q w\,dx\right)\left(\frac{1}{|Q|}\int_Q {w}^{-1/(p-1)}\,dx\right)^{p-1}
\end{align}
(Definition in Grafakos books)
Question. Let $-d<\alpha<d(p-1)$
How calculate (or at least estimate) $\int_{Q}|x|^{\alpha}\,dx$ with $Q$ the cube with center $a$ and sides of length $L$?
For the estimation, I think one can enclose the cube in a sphere with the same center and a radius equal to the distance from the center to a vertex of the cube, but I'm not sure.
Thanks.
